# Windows 7 - Move only files of a given extension while preserving folder structure

Tags: windows-7, file-management

I'm trying to move only a certain type of files, *.txt, from their current location to another folder.  I know that can be done in Windows Explorer with the search feature + drag and drop.  However, that flattens the folder structure and all files end up in the target folder.  What I would like to do is move all those files but preserve their relative folder structure.  So given a source that looks like this:

```
\Source\One\Test1.txt
\Source\One\Test2.avi
\Source\Two\Test3.txt
\Source\Two\Test4.avi
```

And the destination folder:

```
\Destination
```

I'd like a simple way to move or copy the txt files to attain the following:

```
\Destination\One\Test1.txt
\Destination\Two\Test3.txt
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can accomplish this using the Robocopy utility.  Robocopy is standard in Windows Vista, Windows 7 and Windows Server 2008.  If you have a previous version of Windows, you can get it as part of the Windows Resource Kit for your version of Windows.  From a command prompt, use the following command and it should take care of your problem:

`robocopy c:\source c:\destination /E *.txt`

[More information about Robocopy](https://www.windows-commandline.com/robocopy-command-syntax-examples/)

Comment: You can add the /MOV option after /E to move the files. You might also want to check out RichCopy, if you're more comfortable with a GUI: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/2009.04.utilityspotlight.aspx

Comment: Cool utility!  I preferred the /S option but this did exactly what I wanted.

Comment: Thanks Scott; also, to preserve timestamps and such, add "/COPYALL /DCOPY:T ". Note: to use /DCOPY:T, install robocopy version XP026, available via the Robocopy GUI (http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/2006.11.utilityspotlight.aspx). Installing the robocopy gui automatically dumps robocopy.exe into C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32. Note: if you have already installed robocopy via the Microsoft Windows Resource Kit, you will need to rename the version in C:\Program Files\Windows Resource Kits\Tools (I renamed it to robocopyXP010.exe).

Answer (score 0):

Is xcopy available?

`xcopy c:\*.bat z:\targetdir /s`

Works on XP. I don't have Windows 7 available at the moment, but it should work.

Answer (score 0):

In regards to if xcopy is still available, yes it is in both Windows 7 and Windows 8.1. Not sure about Windows 10. I just used it to move a whole bunch of ISO files to one directory. Use xcopy /? from a command prompt to get a list of available Xcopy commands.