# What's a good way to move large amounts of files from one place to another, using the file path?

Tags: windows, file-transfer

I'm going to move my Winamp library from its current location (in various folders inside My Documents) to My Music, but I can't just drag and drop them, as there's thousands of files within My Documents that I don't want moved. I can get the path of every single music file from Winamp, but I don't know any way to move them all.

I'd like some way to maintain their current folder arrangement, and not just dump all the files in a single folder, unorganised.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Intelligent file copy/move software?](http://superuser.com/questions/10721/intelligent-file-copy-move-software)

Comment: Assuming the files are all the same type (or not too many different types), you can just go to your Documents folder, search for eg. `type:mp3`, press Ctrl+A to select all, and drag&drop to the new location. Repeat for each extension.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://superuser.com/questions/112537/windows-7-move-only-files-of-a-given-extension-while-preserving-folder-structu

Comment: Indrek, this flattens the directory structure. He does not want this.

Comment: @gentlesea Ah, good point, didn't think of that. BTW, when replying to someone's comment, you can prepend `@` to their username, this way they'll be notified of your response. See http://superuser.com/editing-help#comment-reply

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
robocopy C:\source C:\destination /S /MOV *.mp3
```

Usage:

```
Usage :: ROBOCOPY source destination [file [file]...] [options]

source :: Source Directory (drive:\path or \\server\share\path).
destination :: Destination Dir  (drive:\path or \\server\share\path).
file :: File(s) to copy  (names/wildcards: default is "*.*").

::
:: Copy options :
::

/S :: copy Subdirectories, but not empty ones.

/MOV :: MOVe files (delete from source after copying).
```

Comment: Yeah, that looks like it'll do it. Much easier than the file paths thing.

Answer (score 0):

Copy the entire my documents folder to a new folder. Then, do a windows find/search in the new folder for *.mp3, sort the results by filetype, then delete non-mp3s.

This will leave you with some useless empty folders, (previously containing office documents without mp3s) which I guess you can purge manually or via some app that deletes empty folders.

A rudimentary solution.